# recreate a figure with TikZ from an entrance exam

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-trees, trees

Could anyone help me recreate this image on tikz? I don't really know where to start

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to TeX StackExchange! The [Ti*k*Z documentation](https://tikz.dev/) is typically a good place to start. What have you tried so far? It'll be easier for others to help you once you've added some code of your own and you let people know where you're stuck.

Comment: When all else fails, read the manual.

Answer (score 6):

Please note that I think I ought not answer do-it-for-mes, but sometimes I do what I believe I ought not.

I'd use Forest. Others would use something else. MetaPost, plain TikZ, `tikz-trees` etc. The tree is super-simple, in fact. The only slightly non-standard bit is the triangular root. The trick here is to use `shape border rotate` so that the shape is rotated but the text is not.

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/714445/
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for descendants={circle,},
  for tree={draw,font=\sffamily,thick,edge+=thick,},
  regular polygon sides=3,
  regular polygon,
  shape border rotate=180,
  inner sep=0pt,  
%  for children={fork sep'=0pt,},% uncomment to remove line between root and edge
  [10 [5] [3 [1][1]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[I can't currently produce images worth anything due to an Okular bug, so I'm not even going to try.]

(*from community*)
[image: result]

Comment: Is it possible to remove the vertical line under the triangle that connects to the horizontal line?

Comment: @Simd See edit. Since this would match the original question, I've included the code here. Since I can't change the image, I've commented it so the output still matches the code. Uncomment to remove that part of the edge. (What it actually does is moves the fork up.)

Answer (score 5):

## A version with tikz alone.

#### Update: A tip to remove the small vertical line under the root

To do this, I build the nodes without tracing the edges. I then build them manually.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
every child node/.style={circle,draw},
edge from parent path={}
]
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3,draw,shape border rotate=60,inner sep=0pt]
(root) {10}[sibling distance=20mm]
child {node {5}}
child {node {3}[sibling distance=10mm]
    child {node {1}}
    child {node {1}}
};
\coordinate (aux) at ($(root-2-1)!.5!(root-2-2)!.5!(root-2)$);
\draw(root-2-1)|-(aux)--(root-2);
\draw(root-2-2)|-(aux)--(root-2);
\draw(root-1)|-(root.south);
\draw(root-2)|-(root.south);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### First answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every child node/.style={circle,draw},
edge from parent path=
{(\tikzparentnode.south) |-($(\tikzparentnode.south)!.5!(\tikzchildnode.north)$)-| (\tikzchildnode.north)}
]
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3,draw,shape border rotate=60,inner sep=0pt]
(root) {10}[level distance =15mm,sibling distance=20mm]
child {node {5}}
child {node {3}[level distance=12mm,sibling distance=10mm]
    child {node {1}}
    child {node {1}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to remove the vertical line under the triangle that connects to the horizontal line?

Comment: I've been looking since the beginning, but so far I haven't gotten there yet.

Comment: That's it, I managed to find a way to remove this little line. The idea is to place the nodes without tracing the edges and to build them manually afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it in elementary steps in `Tikz`, which may be easier for a beginner. Let's arrive here in small steps: start simple and refine.

I suggest:

- to have a look into the turtorials of the [pgfmanual](https://tikz.dev/) and look up all those commands in parallel. (It's less difficult to do than it looks in writing.)
- to simplify some lines as I show in the step-by-step process to better understand, how the result would look like in it's raw or premature state of code.

[image: result]

#### 1. Placing nodes

Start placing nodes first, with dummy text or real content, that doesn't matter. Make sure, they distribute more or less as you want them in the end.

There are many ways to do it. Here I use absolut coordinates, and there are many more. So start with sth. like:

```
...
    \node (T)   at ( 0,-1) {10};
    \node (A1)  at (-2,-2) {5};
...
```

This will

- put nodes
- at the indicated positions (in a cm-raster)
- with some text inside the `{..}`es
- give them names (T), (A1) ... which will make it easy to reference their positions later (see below)

#### 2. Connecting nodes

First, just connect the nodes straight, like so:

```
    \draw (T) -- (A1);
...
    \draw (A2) -- (B1);
...
```

Next, modify the lines a little, using intermediate points for the lower right branch by replacing the `--`s:

```
 %  \draw (A2) -- (B1);
    \draw (A2) |- +(0,-1) -| (B1);
    \draw (A2) |- +(0,-1) -| (B2);
```

This will:

- start at node (A2)
- move downwards, then horizontally
- to a point in relative coordinates (+x=0, +y=-1)
- from there move horizontally than vertically
- until it meets node (B1)

Because you want the triangle to meet the line directly, you can do it a bit different, like this:

```
    \draw (T.south) -| (A1);
```

- start at the south-side of node (T), i.e. it's lower middle
- move horizontally, then vertically
- until you meet node (A1)

#### 3. Formatting nodes

Now let's do some fine tuning:

```
...
 \begin{tikzpicture}[ % self defined styles
    crc/.style={draw,circle,minimum width=6mm},
    tri/.style={draw, minimum width=6mm,inner sep=0mm,
                regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,
                shape border rotate=180},
 ]
    % ~~~ placing the nodes ~~~~~~~~
    \node[tri] (T)  at ( 0,-1) {10};
    \node[crc] (A1) at (-2,-2) {5};
...
```

Nodes have a surrounding shape, which is by default rectangular AND invisible. It adjusts its shapes dimensions automatically according to its content.

To make the shape visible and to modify many things, you can add a list of options to a node, like so:

```
   \node[draw, option=xy, option=qr, ...] at (10,20) {some text};
```

This is clumsy, and many times you want to use a style several times. So you move the definition to the beginning, as shown.

The `crc`-style `crc/.style={draw,circle,minimum width=6mm},`:

- draw (i.e. draws the shape in its default color, which is black)
- changes the shape to a circle
- indirectly adjusts its diameter by saying, how wide the node shall be at least

To have a triangle you need a bit more to draw a 3-sided polygon on its top in a not too large diameter:

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
...
    tri/.style={draw, minimum width=6mm,inner sep=0mm,
                regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,
                shape border rotate=180},
```

#### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[ % self defined styles
    crc/.style={draw,circle,minimum width=6mm},
    tri/.style={draw, minimum width=6mm,inner sep=0mm,
                regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,
                shape border rotate=180},
 ]
    % ~~~ placing the nodes ~~~~~~~~
    \node[tri] (T)  at ( 0,-1) {10};
    \node[crc] (A1) at (-2,-2) {5};
    \node[crc] (A2) at ( 2,-2) {3};
    \node[crc] (B1) at ( 1,-4) {1};
    \node[crc] (B2) at ( 3,-4) {1};
    
    % ~~~ connections ~~~~~~~
    \draw (T.south) -| (A1);
    \draw (T.south) -| (A2);
    
 %  \draw (A2) -- (B1);
    \draw (A2) |- +(0,-1) -| (B1);
    \draw (A2) |- +(0,-1) -| (B2);
    
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks!! im so grateful for this